# Angular: How to map JSON result from HttpClient request to class instances?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have the following code which seems wrong:

```
public search(searchString: string): Observable<Array<ClientSearchResult>> {
    let params = new HttpParams().set('searchString', searchString);

    return this.http
        .get<Array<ClientSearchResult>>(this.searchUrl, { params: params })
        .map((results: ClientSearchResult[]) => results.map((r: ClientSearchResult) => new ClientSearchResult(r)));
}
```

I know that the API is returning a JSON object which is not the same as an instance of my TypeScript class.  However, I want to use properties defined in the TypeScript class.

Is there a better way to map the array coming from my API call to an array that actually consists of instances of `ClientSearchResult`?

Here is the `ClientSearchResult` object:

```
import { Name } from './name';

export class ClientSearchResult {
    public id: string;
    public name: Name;
    public dateOfBirth: Date;
    public socialSecurityNumber: string;

    public get summary(): string {
        let result: string = `${this.name}`;

        if (this.dateOfBirth)
            result += ` | ${this.dateOfBirth.toLocaleDateString()}`;

        return result;
    }

    constructor(source: ClientSearchResult) {
        this.id = source.id;
        this.name = new Name(source.name);
        this.dateOfBirth = source.dateOfBirth? new Date(source.dateOfBirth) : undefined;
        this.socialSecurityNumber = source.socialSecurityNumber;
    }

    public toString(): string {
        return this.summary;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Object.assign(new ClientSearchResult(), decodedJsonObject)` if you don't want to manually set many properties but that's moreorless all.

Comment: could you show us, the constructor of ClientSearchResult ? maybe 'new ClientSearchResult(r)' is not the way to apply a transformation to a ClientSearchResult instance.

Comment: @Luillyfe I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a wonderful library to map json to typescript objects.
https://github.com/shakilsiraj/json-object-mapper

json-object-mapper depends on reflect-metadata library as it is using decorators to serialize and deserialize the data.

Answer (score 1):

As an option you may try TypeScript `as` operator to cast your API response to the ClientSearchResult type.

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

public search(searchString: string): Observable<ClientSearchResult[]> {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('searchString', searchString);
    return this.http.get(this.searchUrl, { params: params })
        .map((results: Response) => results.json() as ClientSearchResult[]);
}
```

This approach requires your model class to be used as an interface, or just to be an interface:

```
interface ClientSearchResult {
  id: number;
  // etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, I'm trying to use the new `HttpClient` instead of `Http`.  `HttpClient` gives me a typed array, not a `Response`.  I'll look into the `as` operator and see if I can do anything with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this very nice (and up-to-date at the time of posting) library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer

It can handle very complex cases with nested classes and more.